# How to search aggregations in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a books index which contains an array of tags (with both text/keyword types), i'd like to offer an autocomplete for tags so users type "ro" and it returns "romance" or "rock and roll".

Here's my mapping:

```
/books {
 ...
  tags: {
    type: 'text',
    field: {
      keyword: {type: 'keyword'}
    }
  }
}
```

Example book

```
{ name: "foo", tags: ['romance', 'story', 'fiction'] }
```

My aggregation for tags:

```
      {
      size: 0,
      aggregations: {
        options: {
          terms: {
            field: `tags.keyword`,
            size: 20
          }
        }
      }
```

How can I only get all distinct tags that match "ro"?

Comment: Have you looked at top hits aggregation? 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: I'm not sure how it would help with this case

Comment: I was hoping you can create top hits aggregation for each tag based on your search query. So, you will have list of top tags with your search.

Comment: The problem is i get other tags not containing with "ro" but they simply happened to be in same documents that have other "ro" tags

Comment: Got it. Will we able to use bucket selector aggregation over that? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply try:

```
GET book/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "tags.keyword": "ro"
    }
  }, "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "options": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags.keyword",
        "size": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But for your use case I suggest to you to build a custom analyzer with ngram filter, like this:

```
    "tags": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "english_custom",
      "fields": {
        "suggester": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "keyword":{
                   "type": "keyword" }
      }
```

The autocomplete analyzer should be something like this:

```
 {"filter":{
     ....

    "autocomplete_filter": {
      "type": "edge_ngram",
      "min_gram": 2,
      "max_gram": 8
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "autocomplete_filter"
      ]
    } 
   }
```

**EDIT:**
Could you play with the include clause in terms aggregation?

```
GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tags.keyword",
                "include" : "ro.*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only applies a filter on the documents that have a tag matching "ro", I still get sibling tags that have no "ro".

Comment: The problem is i get other tags not containing with "ro" but they simply happened to be in same documents that have other "ro" tags

Comment: Include works!! but how can i make it case insensitive, the regex doesn't seem to have a flag like /i?

Comment: @Ryan you can't now, you should insert your tags in lowercase in indexing time, or add the lowercase filter to the analyzer for field that has text datatype, or add lowercase to the normalizer for field with keyword datatype

Comment: Thanks for help so much!

Comment: It seems that normalizer really affects the data returned (even though it helps with my issue) any workaround to keep the data's case intact?

Comment: @Ryan What do you mean that normalizer affects the data? it is a token filter and not a mapping char filter. Have you tested the solution yet?

Comment: If i use a lowercase normalizer on the keyword, the agg values returned are all lowercased, (the _source isn't but i don't need that)

Comment: Had to just use this hacky regex to match lowercase without a normalizer: `.*[Bb][Ll][Aa][Bb][Ll][Aa].*`

Comment: @Ryan this is an awesome solution!